# Symfony default session variabe

Tags: php, symfony

Could you help me. How can I set default varibles in session in pre-initialization framework, not in some controller? thanks

Comment: Did you means declare session variable before your first controller ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony has events to which you can attach your own `event listener`. And the one you could attach your event listener would be `kernel.request`. Here is the sample **source code** you can use.

First, inside your `services.yml` file under `Resources/config` folder:

```
services:
  listener.my_request_listener:
    class: My\AwesomeBundle\Listener\MyListener
    arguments: [ @session ]
    tags:
      - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
```

Second, your `MyListener`will look like this:

```
namespace My\AwesomeBundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session;

class MyListener
{
    protected $session;

    public function __construct(SessionInterface $session)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $kernel    = $event->getKernel();
        $request   = $event->getRequest();
        //Your logic goes here
        if($this->session->has('someKey')){
            $this->session->set('someKey','newvalue');
        }
    }
}
```